# Updating Highcharts column chart based on drop down-menu

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to have Highcharts do the following: I want to show a column chart with three columns. The two first are to remain constant, the third is to be updated multiple times based on what the user chooses from a drop down-menu.

Choosing from the drop down-menu, I am able to have the third column update. If it's showing "Name 3" initially, choosing "Name 4" from the drop down menu will correctly replace the column. Choosing "Name 5" causes another correct replacement. However, if I then choose "Name 3" again, only the label will update, while the column and the y-value in the tooltip will not. Thus, it will say "Name 3", but use the y-value for "Name 5". How do I fix this behaviour?

The important thing here is user control of column 3. It would be okay to only show 2 column initially, if it's easier.

Code:

```
var data = {
    "10 - Name 1": [700000],
    "1001 - Name 2": [750000],
    "1000 - Name 3": [800000],
    "1002 - Name 4": [900000],
    "1003 - Name 5": [950000]
};
var chart = Highcharts.chart('fig8', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        animation: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: "10 - Name 1",
        data: data["10 - Name 1"]
    }, {
        name: "1001 - Name 2",
        data: data["1001 - Name 2"]
    }, {
        name: "1000 - Name 3",
        data: data["1000 - Name 3"]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Some metric'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Choose unit from drop down to alter third column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
});
$("#sel").change(function() {
    chart.series[2].update({
        name: this.value,
        data: data[this.value]
    });
});
```

Here's a stripped down example: https://jsfiddle.net/RuneS/soh8vw79/10/

Comment: In short, you are creating a reference to that `data` object, and every update of the select box is updating the actual data object, and the object value for option 3 is overwritten with the previous selection (by updating the series data which references the object). There may be better solutions, but the easy one is to create one object for the select box, and another one for the chart config: https://jsfiddle.net/soh8vw79/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jlbriggs is correct. Although the docs for [`update()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update) don't say anything about it, it is mentioned in the docs for [`setData()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData): When updating series data, the default behavior is to update the values in the original data array instead of replacing the whole array.

In your case, that means that "Name 3"'s value is overwritten by the others' values when you select from the dropdown. There are at least two ways to fix this:

1. Force Highcharts to replace the data array by calling `setData()` with the `updatePoints` parameter instead of sending the data with `update()`:

   ```js
   $("#sel").change(function() {
       var unit = this.value,
           val = data[unit],
           ser = chart.series[2];

       ser.update({ name: unit }, false);

       //... false): Replace the series' data array instead of updating its values,
       //(which would alter the original array in the global `data` object).
       //https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData
       ser.setData(val, true, true, false);
   });
   ```

   https://jsfiddle.net/soh8vw79/22
2. Don't give Highcharts the original array, but a copy of it. That way, updating the values won't affect the original data (similar to @jlbriggs solution). *Added bonus: Smooth animation*:

   ```js
   ...
   series: [{
       name: "10 - Name 1",
       data: data["10 - Name 1"]
   }, {
       name: "1001 - Name 2",
       data: data["1001 - Name 2"]
   }, {
       name: "1000 - Name 3",
       //Here, we use `.slice()` to make a copy of the original array,
       //so that future updates don't change the original values in the global `data` object:
       data: data["1000 - Name 3"].slice()
   }],
   ...
   ```

   https://jsfiddle.net/soh8vw79/23